# Выполнение команды от другого пользователя

Tags: linux, unix

Есть пользователь test и test1. Оба с обычными правами. Я работаю с пользователем test, известно что test1 не имеет пароля, и именно от него я хочу выполнить команду. Попробовал сделать так:

```
su test1 -c whoami
```

Но оно хочет какой-то пароль, хотя его нет. Возможно есть другие решения? Sudo не вариант так как пользователь test не прописан в файле sudoers.

```
OS: FreeBSD 8.1 amd64
```

Comment: Ну если нет у `test1` пароля - при запросе пароля нажмите `Enter` да и всё.

Comment: Пробовал, дает ошибку: Сбой при проверке подлинности. Если запускать от рута то все работает, но суть в том что у меня обычный пользователь.

Answer (score 3):

нет пароля — значит, под именем этого пользователя нельзя аутентифицироваться, что и требуется при использовании программы *su* (у суперпользователя есть привилегия аутентифицироваться с помощью этой программы без использования пароля пользователя).

мне известно как минимум два варианта решения:

1. присвойте пароль этому пользователю. от имени суперпользователя:

   ```
   # passwd test1
   ```
2. если программа *sudo* установлена, добавьте в `/etc/sudoers`, например, такую строку:

   ```
   test ALL = (test1) ALL
   ```

   это даст возможность пользователю *test* выполнять любые программы/команды от имени пользователя *test1*:

   ```
   $ sudo -u test1 whoami
   ```

   запрашиваться при этом будет пароль пользователя *test*.

   можно сделать и без запроса пароля, добавив директиву `NOPASSWD:` в приведённую выше строку:

   ```
   test ALL = (test1) NOPASSWD: ALL
   ```