# Использование ssh-ключа от другого пользователя при выполнении скрипта

Tags: centos, ssh, ssh-key

На **host1** есть 2 пользователя - *user1* и *user2*. Так же у **user1** в домашней лежит скрипт *run.sh*, который в процессе выполнения выкачивает файлы через rsync с хоста **host2**, и для авторизации используется ключ пользователя *user1*.
Есть необходимость из-под пользователя ***user2*** запускать скрипт */home/user1/run.sh* *так, что бы он во время своей работы для авторизации на* ***host2*** ***использовал ключ от*** ***user1***.
Другими словами, пользователь user2 не должен иметь возможности авторизоваться по ssh на хосте host2 с помощью ключа user1, но должен уметь запускать скрипт польщователя user1, который в свою очередь авторизуется без проблем.
Подскажите, возможно такое реализовать? Если да, то как?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/473615/178576

Comment: Не работает. Скрипт от user2 запустить можно, а вот ключ другой пользователь "не видит" - во время выполнения скрипта при авторизации просит ввести пароль от host2

Comment: если у вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, нажав на соответсвующую кнопку в правом верхнем углу страницы. не забудьте при этом про [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить пользователя User2 в группе User1, должно сработать.
Либо на скрипт  /home/user1/run.sh  установить права +x
Из под User1:
    chmod +x  /home/user1/run.sh

Comment: не сработало. Скрипт запускается из-под user2, но ssh-ключ от user1 использовать не хочет

Comment: У вас усложненная схема, может имеет смысл сделать авторизацию для юзера  по паролю?